# c++ function overloading, making fwrite/fread act like PHP versions

Tags: c++, windows, overloading

I'm used to the PHP fwrite/fread parameter orders, and i want to make them the same in C++
too.

I want it to work with char and string types, and also any data type i put in it (only if length is defined).

I am total noob on c++, this is what i made so far:
**Edit:** fixed the std::string &buf

```
size_t fwrite(FILE *fp, const std::string &buf, const size_t len = SIZE_MAX){
    if(len == SIZE_MAX){
        return fwrite(buf.c_str(), 1, buf.length(), fp);
    }else{
        return fwrite(buf.c_str(), 1, len, fp);
    }
}

size_t fwrite(FILE *fp, const void *buf, const size_t len = SIZE_MAX){
    if(len == SIZE_MAX){
        return fwrite((const char *)buf, 1, strlen((const char *)buf), fp);
    }else{
        return fwrite(buf, 1, len, fp);
    }
}
```

Should this work just fine? And how should this be done if i wanted to do it the absolutely best possible way?

Comment: The best possible way is to use C++ instead of trying to recreate php. Redefining standard functions to take different arguments is a recipe for bugs and confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write to a file in the best possible way, you should use std::iostreams. Dealing with the length of the buffer manually is a recipe for problems.

Also, the top overload should take a const std::string&, not const std::string.

However, I don't see any actual bugs.

Comment: could you explain what disadvantages/problems it causes when i dont use the "std::string &buf" ? seems to work without it too.

Comment: if you miss off the & you cause a copy of the object to be made which can be expensive in terms of CPU & memory.

Comment: It's like a pointer, except the compiler handles all the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

fwrite / fread don't really work very well with objects; so as @DeadMG says you'd be better of with streams.

something like:

```
cout << str << endl;
```

It's a much more OO way of doing things - you can overload the operators within the objects  to handle the different requirements of each individual object.

This isn't the right sort of overloading of functions IMO. If anything these functions should be methods within the object.